# Android loading webview content full screen

Tags: android

When I give the following url to webview in android the content is getting displayed top left corner only. I want to make it full screen(content only). How can I make it?

http://staging.snagfilms.com/modules/html5player.jsp?filmId=ed9195a0-a748-11e0-a92a-0026bb61d036&w=500&html5=1

Xml:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_browser_new1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.verizon.viewdini.ui.custom.CustomFacedWebView
            android:id="@+id/web_wrap_browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
myWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: Code and XML layout code is needed to find out issue.

Comment: I have updated code Bhuro

Comment: what worked for you?? @RamachandraReddyAvula

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code:**

```
    Webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    this.webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answe dude. But its not showing the content fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Use This this lines in xml

```
<WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webview_compontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"   
    />
```

enable the following setting lines also.

```
 WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is not giving me the expected result dude

Comment: @RamachandraReddyAvula have you found any solution for this, because i could not able to load full data into the webview from url

Answer (score 0):

add this to your HTML file:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>`

after that, set this in your code:

`WebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Hope this will work.
In case setLoadWithOverviewMode doesn't work as you like, you can calculate the scale ratio between your website'sizee and the webview's size, then apply that scale with

`WebView.setInitialScale(the_scale_ratio);`

Remember to remove "viewport" tag in the HTML file in this case.

Answer (score 0):

three steps to make it work.

1. make layout full screen with no padding, no margin.
2. make you web page surrounding no padding, no margin.
3. make you web page surrounding no negative left, right, top, bottom floating.